# Not able to specify a condition for db[collection].distinct

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Have been trying to solve it by myself so we have the following statement:

> #### Exercise 5.1 (code) Using the data stored in the MongoDB collection with the reviews, count
>
> - The **number of distinct users** who made a review (i.e. count the number of distinct values for the field **reviewerID**)
> - The **number of distinct users who gave at least one bad rating (less or equal that 2 stars)**
> - The **number of distinct books** which received a review (i.e. count the number of distinct values for field **asin**).

Here is my code:

```
n_users = len(db[reviews_collection].distinct("reviewerID"))
n_users_bad_rating = len(db[reviews_collection].distinct("reviewerID", {"overall": {"$lte": 2.0}}))
n_books = len(db[reviews_collection].distinct("asin"))

print(f"There are {n_users} distinct users.")
print(f"There are {n_users_bad_rating} distinct users who gave at least one bad rating (less or equal to 2 stars).")
print(f"There are {n_books} distinct books in the reviews.")
```

Here is the output I get:

> There are 3613 distinct users.
> There are 0 distinct users who gave at least one bad rating (less or equal to 2 stars).
> There are 3807 distinct books in the reviews.

Example of what the data in the collection looks like:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('6252c21c2ee307d4d522af0a'),
 'appreciation': 'liked',
 'asin': 'B000R93D4Y',
 'book_index': 0,
 'helpful': [3, 3],
 'overall': 5.0,
 'reviewText': 'A strange world full of strange creatures, knights, and '
               'beautiful maidens.  The magical aspect of healing was a nice '
               'touch.',
 'reviewTime': '06 23, 2013',
 'reviewerID': 'A195CNOUUIT4SU',
 'summary': 'Great tale of dragons',
 'train_val_test': 'train',
 'unixReviewTime': 1371945600,
 'user_index': 0}
```

**Question**: Why am I unable to use conditions? I have other exercices in the notebook where am I asked to query the database it works perfectly fine except if I try to specify conditions. When I use a loop it tells me that I have a "TypeError: string indexes must be int"

Comment: distinct() comand expect only string field name , but you can identify distinct values not only with distinct() command , but also via aggregation framework group pipleine where you can also add match stage to be able to add conditions ...

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I'll try to find how to use it, it's just that the teacher asked us to use distinct

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option how to find distinct values for reviewerID having overall <=2 via aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $match: {
  "overall": {
    "$lte": 2.0
  }
 }
},
{
 "$group": {
  "_id": "TotalUnique",
  "unique": {
    "$addToSet": "$reviewerID"
  }
 }
}
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S5PYm4J248q)

Comment: Hey, it works like a charm, I then get a list but seems like I can't use count or len() on it, is that normal?

Comment: this is normal , you get the final result in single final  line , you dont need to count ...

Comment: But you can use aggregation operations to count like $size  to count the distict elements,example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VHyINikt_Kz

Comment: I agree, but I need to print the result at the end